# how do I set a value of a textbox in Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

how do I set a value of a textbox in Visual C++?
I have been trying the following but the line strTemp.Format("%d", nNbr); does not compile
thanks

```
        int nNbr = 5;
    CString strTemp;
    strTemp.Format("%d", nNbr);

    textBox.SetWindowTextW(strTemp);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to use the [_T](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/8ce6ddef-3f1a-4033-a28b-54af91766e9f) macro in order to support both `ANSI` and `UNICODE` builds of your application:

```
int nNbr = 5;
CString strTemp;
strTemp.Format(_T("%d"), nNbr);
textBox.SetWindowText(strTemp);
```